# How to configure nginx to proxy another service serving http and https on different ports?

Tags: http, redirect, https, proxy, nginx

Use case:

- Using nginx as a frontend for several websites / services running on both 80 and 443 (several virtual hosts).
- Having service x running on localhost that serves http:8090 and https:8099

How do I need to configure nginx so people can access using only the name, without specifying the port.

Answer (score 1):

This a fairly normal setup. Configure the hosts served directly on Nginx as normal.  Since they need to listen on both 80 and 443, each host entry would have this in it:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    listen  443 ssl;
}
```

The [Nginx SSL docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule) has the full details.

Then proxy traffic for one `server{}` definition to the backend service:

```
server {
     server_name  example.com;
     location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090; }
}
```

You only need one proxy connection to the backend server, either 'http' or 'https'. If the connection between the two servers is secure, you can 'http', even for connections that arrive to nginx over https. This might be appropriate if the service is on the same machine. Otherwise, all the traffic could be proxied through https if the connection between nginx and the backend server needs to be secured.

Comment: This provides no solution for https.

Comment: Not sure I like the idea of the connection between the nginx server and the destination http server being unsecured, even if what you say is possible (nginx can pass https traffic over http to destination server). A majority of the time, the http server is not resident on the same server as nginx, due to scaling out of edge nodes, which would mean the connection from nginx to destination http would be unsecure.

Answer (score -1):

We use the following with our host:

```
http {
    server {
      server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
      listen *:80;

      location / {
          proxy_pass $scheme://<origin>$uri$is_args$args;
          include basic-proxy-settings.conf;
      }
    }
    server {
      server_name ~^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;
      listen *:443 ssl;

      location / {
          proxy_pass $scheme://<origin>$uri$is_args$args;
          include basic-proxy-settings.conf;
      }
      include ssl-settings.conf;
    }
}
```

This allows our upstream proxy to talk to our origin server over HTTP when a request is made by a client for an insecure resource, and over SSL/HTTPS when a request is made for a secure one. It also allows our origin servers to be in charge of forcing redirects to secure connections, etc.

Next time, why not provide a code sample detailing what you've tried, what has worked, and what hasn't?

Comment: It's not at all clear what is in `basic-proxy-settings.conf` and `ssl-settings.conf`. These files contain the important parts.